# Can I have a second sound system running on one Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

Suppose I have a pair of headphones plugged into the usual sound system that is supplied with an ordinary Windows 7-based machine. I add some hypothetical combination of hardware and software to that machine and plug a speaker system into it. Now I can listen to, say, something on youtube on a browser whilst some other software periodically makes announcements on the speaker.

Is this possible? (Why or why not?)

Comment: You could use a virtual machine as this hypothetical software to emulate another sound output device through wherever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need another sound card. If you have multiple sound cards you could route them in the mixer to do almost anything.

for example use VLC  and set the output to the new card while windows media player will use the default player setup in the control panel.